# PieChart truncates Labels when displayed 3D

Tags: .net, winforms, charts, label, mschart

I filled my WinForms pie chart with a bunch of points manually and ensured that each point has the same labeltext with 3 rows. Displaying this chart two dimensional works pretty fine.

Setting the ChartAreas Property `Area3dStyle.Enable3d = true` truncates some labels' lines for some reason. This behavior only appears if I reduce the size of the chart.

[image]

This appears both at runtime and designtime.
Is there any possibility to keep a pie chart from truncating lines of its segments' labels?